# Função que faz a transposta de uma matriz, usando passagem por referencia

Tags: c, matriz

Eu preciso fazer uma função que passando uma matrizA por referência, a matrizA viraria a transposta da matrizA. Eu tentei usando uma matriz auxiliar, só que não esta dando certo. Tem que ser uma matriz 5x5.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void Transposta(int *MatrizA[][5]){
    int MatrizAux[5][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            MatrizAux[i][j] = *MatrizA[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            *MatrizA[j][i] = MatrizAux[i][j];
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int Matriz[5][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            Matriz[i][j] = i+j;
        }
    }
    Transposta(&Matriz);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            printf("| %d |", Matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O que está acontecendo é que você está trocando cda elemento duas vezes, o que faz com que fique igual ao original. Tente: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < 5; j++) {
          int aux = MatrizA[i][j];
          MatrizA[i][j] = MatrizA[j][i];
          MatrizA[j][i] = aux;
        }
    }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matriz que você criou é igual a:

```
|  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |
|  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |
|  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |
|  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |
|  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |
```

Ou seja, é uma [matriz simétrica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix), o que significa que ela é igual à sua transposta. Portanto, não é um bom exemplo para você testar se a função `transposta` está funcionando.

Então primeiro vamos modificar um pouco o primeiro *loop*:

```
for (int i = 0, c = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++, c++) {
        matriz[i][j] = c;
    }
}
```

Isso cria a seguinte matriz:

```
|  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |
|  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
```

Agora sim podemos obter a transposta e saber se funcionou.

---

Como a matriz é quadrada, você não precisa percorrer todos os elementos. A diagonal permanece a mesma, e você só precisa percorrer uma das "metades" (ou a parte "à direita" ou "à esquerda" da diagonal) e trocar com a posição "oposta" correspondente:

```
void transposta(int matriz[][5]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) { // começa em 1, pois ignora a diagonal
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { // só vai até `i` (até a diagonal), não precisa ir até o fim
            // troca os elementos de posição
            int aux = matriz[i][j];
            matriz[i][j] = matriz[j][i];
            matriz[j][i] = aux;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int matriz[5][5];
    for (int i = 0, c = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++, c++) {
            matriz[i][j] = c;
        }
    }

    printf("original:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("| %2d ", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("|\n");
    }

    transposta(matriz);
    printf("transposta:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("| %2d ", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("|\n");
    }
}
```

Também mudei um pouco a saída: você estava imprimindo `||` entre os elementos, mudei para imprimir apenas um. A saída é:

```
original:
|  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |
|  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
transposta:
|  0 |  5 | 10 | 15 | 20 |
|  1 |  6 | 11 | 16 | 21 |
|  2 |  7 | 12 | 17 | 22 |
|  3 |  8 | 13 | 18 | 23 |
|  4 |  9 | 14 | 19 | 24 |
```